# officejs: How to build a combo chart in Excel

Tags: excel, charts, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I need to implement a combo chart to replicate an existing chart design in Excel. The chart is a combination of Clustered Column and Line with markers. I cannot find the obvious way to do it in Excel JS Addin API.

Can this be done? Any examples ?

Answer (score 1):

The [Work with charts using the Excel JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-charts) article provides code samples that show how to perform common tasks with charts using the `Excel JavaScript API`. For the complete list of properties and methods that the `Chart` and `ChartCollection` objects support, see [Chart Object (JavaScript API for Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.chart) and [Chart Collection Object (JavaScript API for Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.chartcollection).

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: `Type: product feature request` at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: Thanks Eugene. Indeed I can read documentation which has no mention of Combo charts which is the fundamental part of my question. I am not interested in basic generic simple API to insert a chart..... Looks like Microsoft is not interested in investing into robust and comprehensive officeJS solution ....just like lack of support for combo charts, there is absolutely no API support in Chart for retrieving and manipulating object like Back Wall, Floor in 3D charts.....pro forma simplistic chart construction support is indeed there...

Comment: You can post a feature request at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: Is there a place where I can find the release schedule, past release history with feature list, planned features, future releases etc ????